# Opening XLS file in browser window from Java

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee

I'm writing a program in JavaEE and my boss has tasked me with uploading an XLS file, query the contents, output to an XLS file, and then open it in a browser window.  I did all that, except the last part, where I can't figure out how to open it in a browser.  This code is something I tried, but I get

13:47:13,297 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: missing ) after argument list (#1) in  at line number 1

Anyone got any ideas?

```
        String outWindowOpen = "window.open(C:\\test\\ApromPromSN\\book1.xls);";

        // create a script engine manager
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
         // create a JavaScript engine
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
         // evaluate JavaScript code from String
        engine.eval(outWindowOpen);
```